# Sqlite3 ODBC Driver over Network/Sharepoint slow

Tags: sqlite, networking, connection, odbc, adodb

Does anyone understand this driver fully? Perhaps it's not the driver, or the ODBC connection. It's really quick local, however it 'seems' like it loads/reads the whole .db (sqlite) file when connecting over both network drives or on Sharepoint. The first time I connect via ADODB using the driver, there is a long delay.. subsequent queries are fast to the file on the network.

I'm using VBA in Excel in this scenario and ADODB connection. THis happens during opening the connection. I want to know what is happening in the 8-20 seconds of connecting the first time. I can pull subsequent queries of 50k records from the DB extremely quickly.

I realize this may be some sort of network authentication, but something else is happening as well. I'm not sure what i can do to improve this delay connecting. It would be huge as we have so many things that could deployed via sqlite and read so much quicker than Sharepoint lists or Access/Excel files. We don't have the option of using real RDBMS. That requires corporate IT, which is the slowest and most bloated system ever invented. We want the ability to create information in a database ad hoc. Structured on-demand. However it has to be a centralized repository on a network. Sqlite could potentially provide that.

Comment: You are aware that you can use Access in conjunction with SharePoint? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/publish-a-database-to-a-sharepoint-site-8287ed04-9c65-46c4-bbdb-c965c56b018c - try to work with SharePoint instead of against it. With SQLite, the driver has to lock and download the SQLite file every time it is accessed. This is obviously slow for the first time and I guess then the file is cached locally.

Comment: SharePoint lists are slow and unreliable on our farm.. Regardless, our users wouldn't use Access so it would begin to get elaborate opening it in background. we sometimes have more data than is realistic in this setup. I had high hopes for SharePoint at one point but it's either poorly administered or it's never improved.  Testing Friday downloading sqlite files to c'\temp and having vba query local is way more effecient than SharePoint or access. At worst I'd look for solutions using this model.

Comment: In one case the larger sqlite dB is faster to open a ccnnection to.  I might try different locks just for reading or rarely updated files on the network. Size becomes an issue for our larger reports in either case.